# Get mutplie values from a dict at once

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary that contains values that I need in my function.

Currently, I extract the values one by one and store them in local variable for further processing. like so:

```
def func(the_dict):
    a=the_dict['a']
    b=the_dict['b']
    b=the_dict['c']
```

the problem is that its a bit verbose, is there a way to extract the variable in a more concise way?

Comment: Why not just refer to them in the dictionary instead of assigning them to new references?

Comment: Do you need all the values in the dict or just specific ones?

Comment: Before someone tries to suggest `locals().update(the_dict)`: no. That doesn't actually work.

Comment: @Mo H: i need a small subset of the values

Comment: @user2357112: You sure?

Comment: @Blender: [Yes, I'm sure.](http://ideone.com/5Hceyi)

Comment: @user2357112: Whoops, had a global named `a`. You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use map and unpack:

```
a, b, c = map(the_dict.get,("a","b","c"))
print(a,b,c)
```

Comment: nice.is there any way to avoid specifing the variable name twice?

Comment: @yigal, not sure I understand, if you want to create variable you need to use a,b,c = , if you want specific values you need to pass the keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get multiple values at once:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> the_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> a, b, c = itemgetter('a', 'b', 'c')(the_dict)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```